# Looking to change the size of a homepage image

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website using the Arcade Pro theme. The theme is designed with a full-page homepage image and I would like to change it so visitors don't have to scroll to view my articles. The website address is: http://cricketyorkshire.com

Could you suggest what code tweaks to try and make the homepage image no longer full-screen and what specific wordpress files I need to alter?

Ideas welcomed. Very happy with the theme but prob losing visitors who won't scroll past the homepage image to access the latest articles.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the height of the image?

Comment: Hi Hareesh, I haven't as yet but mainly because I wouldn't know which WP source file to amend or line of code. The theme creator said it was coded so that the homepage was full-screen and presumably re-sizes to be responsive so unsure if it's as simple as altering dimensions. However, I have a staging site so certainly scope to tinker. Any tips on trying to shorten that image would be appreciated from the community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your style.css file.

```
.title-card {
    height: 50% !important;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Hareesh, this looks to have worked so thanks, really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help you. :)